# Internet connection stops randomly

Tags: drivers, internet, connection

After updating my Ubuntu to 15.04 my internet connection stops working randomly. 
It does not matter if it's connected through wifi or cable. It only stops working without saying it is not connected on the status bar.
The applications cannot connect.

Comment: Can you add some more detail and try some trouble shooting. When it seems disconnected:  does network manager indicate that it IS connected? can you `ping google.com` ? does `ifconfig` have information?

Comment: Can you get it to start working again by `ifdown em1`, then `ifup em1` (or whatever your device is)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the command `sudo apt-get remove network-manager*`

This might work, since it removes the network manager. Also turn off the WiFi and unplug the network cable and plug it back ,try vice versa too. hope this will work.